# Clickable "ChipField" element

Tags: react-admin

In the list page, I'm using a component as follows in the Datagrid

```
<ArrayField source="functions">
    <SingleFieldList>
        <ChipField source="id" />
    </SingleFieldList>
</ArrayField>
```

But this causes a clickable element in the grid. I don't want this element to be clickable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest version of react-admin [2.3](https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/09/07/react-admin-2-3.html), adding `linkType={false}` to your `<SingleFieldList>` will do the work. 
Your snippet will become:

```
<ArrayField source="functions">
    <SingleFieldList linkType={false}>
         <ChipField source="id" />
    </SingleFieldList>
</ArrayField>
```

Comment: This answer helped me with figuring out that changing the link type to `linkType="show"` is also possible.